# functions only returning 1?

Tags: c, menu, return, function-call

I'm having an issue where my functions seems to be only returning one. I thought that I was returning the functions correctly but it seems that I am not.

```
char goAgain()
{
char ch;
do
{
    printf("Would you like to go again? ");
    ch = getchar();
    while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n');
}while(ch != 'n' || 'y');

return ch;
}


double findMedian(int array[], int length)
{
int mid;
double median, medianLeft, medianRight;
if(length % 2 == 0)
{
    mid = length / 2;
//      medianLeft = array[mid];
//      medianRight = array[mid + 1];
}
else
{
    mid = length / 2;
    median = array[mid];
}

return median;
}
```

this is how I am calling the median

```
double mean = findMedian(array, length);
```

why is it only giving me a one in my return. also when i try to repeat the goAgain I don't get the correct ch to be returned either.

```
option = goAgain();
```

things are a lot different in the c world compared to the java world.

```
do
{
    int num = menu();

    if(num == 1)
        fillArray(array, size);
    else if(num == 2)
    {
        int newSize = readNum();
        fillArray(array, newSize);
    }
    else if(num == 3)
    {
        int length = size;
        sortArray(array);
        double mean = findMean(array, length);
        double median = findMedian(array, length);
        printResults(mean, median);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid number\n");
        num = menu();
    }

    option = goAgain();
}while(option == 'y');
```

Comment: What should `findMedian` return if `(length % 2 != 0)`? 0?

Comment: `if(length % 2 == 0)` then you don't initialise `median` to any value, and therefore return something random.

Comment: `while(ch != 'n' || 'y')` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: if     findMedian turns out to be false then it will be an odd length for the array

Comment: i'm not worried about the    if(length%2==0) right now, it will be dealt with at a later time @NikBougalis what does it do?

Comment: @kevorski You're not compiling with warnings (or not reading them). Add `-Wall` to your compile flags.

Comment: @PerJohansson I'm not getting any compiler errors. And in Geany it is already set for the -Wall

Comment: @kevorski It's really a pity if a compiler doesn't warn on something like `while(ch != 'n' || 'y')` which may be legal in terms of syntax but is almost *certainly* wrong.

Comment: i still don't understand why it is returning a 1 as the median. i even changed some of the code to be    `if(length % 2 == 0)
    {
    mid = length / 2;
    medianLeft = array[mid + 1];
       return medianLeft;
     }
      else
     {
      mid = length / 2;
      median = array[mid];
      return median;
     }`

there we go, got the code section working

Comment: @kevorski you're right, seem even gcc 4.7 doesn't warn about that. clang does though.

Comment: why is my menu only being displayed once. it will ask to go again and then i hit y and it just stays there until i hit n

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This condition:

```
(ch != 'n' || 'y')
```

Is probably not doing what you want.  It is interpreted by the compiler like this:

```
((ch != 'n') || 'y')
```

Which means "if `ch` is not the character `n` OR if the character `y`". If your machine uses ASCII, then `y` has the value 121. What happens if you do:

```
((whatever) || 121)
```

For the boolean `OR` operator (`||`) the value `0` represents false and every other value represents true. And what do you get when at least least of the operands of a boolean OR operation are true? You get true.

So, your condition is, essentially, the same as simply writing

```
 (1)
```

It looks like you want:

```
(ch != 'n' && ch != 'y');
```

Comment: Actually, `(ch != 'n' || 'y');` would always evaluate to `true` because `'y'` is always non-zero.

Comment: Isn't that what I have there?

Comment: No... `(ch != 1)` implies it could evaluate to `false` if `ch == 1` -- you would mean `( ch !='n' || 'y')` is the same as saying `( true )`

Comment: But my answer doesn't have `(ch != 1)` anywhere in it.

Comment: Ah... it was edited after I responded (or while I was responding). It originally stated `(ch != 1)` prior to the edit. Disregard.

Comment: ok that fixed that problem. so in c most return statements are 1 or 0?

Comment: @kevorski no - the result of the logical operators `&&` and `||` will be either 0 which means the operation returned "false" or some other value (perhaps 1, but I don't *think* it's mandated by the standard) which means the operation returned "true".

Comment: @NikBougalis - `&&` and `||` and `!` always result in `0` or `1`.  You might be thinking of the bitwise operators `&` and `|`?

Comment: @CarlNorum No - I meant that I wasn't sure if a return of `1` was *mandated* by the standard instead of leaving it up to the implementation to return whatever non-zero number is convenient.

Comment: @NikBougalis, yeah I understood that.  My comment was just meant to let you know that, yes, the standard does mandate the `1`.  I think we're on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

When this:

```
if(length % 2 == 0)
```

... evaluates `true`, you don't calculate a value for `median`, yet still return it.

(And then add in whatever becomes from Carl's answer, which is dealing with the "and also" part of your question!)

Comment: the thing that i'm doing right now is just an odd length for the array , once i get the odd part working i will concentrate on what the even will return